# blank pages rendered - codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just moved my codeigniter app from one machine to another.
I’m getting the above error message.

here’s what I’ve checked so far:

config.php for code igniter has the following:

```
 $config[‘base_url’] = ‘http://myserver/myapp/’;
```

when i navigate to

```
     http://myserver/myapp/index.php
```

i don,‘t get any error messages, and nothing is displayed /rendered.  I do a view source and there is no html on the page. (btw.  I have specified “welcome” as my default controller in routes).  when i navigate to:

```
     http://myserver/myapp/index.php/welcome
```

it's the same result.

I checked my apache2 access log this is what it contains:

```
   127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2012:13:27:37 -0400] "GET /myapp/index.php/welcome HTTP/1.1" 200 293 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"
```

127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2012:13:27:48 -0400] "GET /myapp/index.php/switches HTTP/1.1" 200 293 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"

shouldn’t it have

```
     “GET http://myserver/myapp/index.php/welcome”
```

instead of just

```
     “myapp/welcome”?
```

also i tried looking up the apache error message # 293 but i haven't come across anything that is helpful for troubleshooting.

The thing is other applications work.  So i can do

```
     “http://myserver/phpmyadmin”
```

and it works.
Also i created a test.php page in my “myapp” folder and it works too.

I’m not using .htaccess as far as i can tell.  I have the following variables set in my config.php for codeigniter:

```
       $config[‘index_page’] = ‘index.php’;
       $config[‘uri_protocol’] = ‘AUTO’;
```

Error logging is turned on both in the php.ini file and also in the code igniter config file.

Comment: are you sure there is not .htacess file that is suppressing the index.php

Comment: you have the "white screen of death". work backwards - install a "clean" version of Codeigniter and see if that works - then slowly move forward from there.

Comment: have you checked the .htaccess file rewrite rules ??

Comment: I checked and i have no htaccess file in myapp or it's subfolders...

Comment: TheShiftExchange - Thanks. I did that and the new site is working... but I would like to know why existing site doesn't work...  it's driving me mad!  =)

Comment: ok - so now what you do is 'slowly' transition your site across. i.e. start with your site config - move it to the 'new' site. then change your main controller, then your db etc etc - until the error shows itself.

Comment: btw - did you move from a windows server to a linux server? if so - its probably a "case sensitive" file issue

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, can you post your suggestion to start with a fresh copy as an answer?  the problem did reveal itself.  ends up that somehow i managed to not copy over the autoload.php...where i was auto loading the url helper.  ci was dying but not reporting errors.  I still don't know why that's the case.  but adding in controllers one by one was a good methodology for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the "white screen of death". work backwards - install a "clean" version of Codeigniter and see if that works - then slowly move forward from there.

Then what you do is 'slowly' transition your site across. i.e. start with your site config - move it to the 'new' site. then change your main controller, then your db etc etc - until the error shows itself.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you are using curly quotes rather than the regular ones?

`$config[‘base_url’] = ‘http://myserver/myapp/’;`

is different than

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://myserver/myapp/';`

Comment: I don't think so.... i think they look different because I copied and pasted from VI..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the autoload.php contained the helper class 'url'. On the new machine, this item was not set. Its unclear why this file was the only one not copied over.. or overwritten properly.  In any case,  CI was dying on my pages because i make calls to base_url().  It's still unclear why the error messages have not been displayed.
For now, the app is back up and running.  I am still trying to figure out why PHP errors are not displayed but i will doulbe check everything first before posting back.

Thanks all.

Comment: Modify php.ini to display errors. Find the line in php.ini that reads `display_errors`, and ensure it is set to On. Also, ensure `error_reporting` is set to E_ALL in the same file. On debian based systems you can find php.ini in `/etc/php5/apache2/` Obviously, you'll want to suppress the errors when you app is in production.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue on moving server where php short tags `<?= ?>` were not enabled in php.ini
this meant I was getting a blank page and this in the html source (output by layout->render_page):

```
<?= $header; ?>
<?= $contents; ?>
<?= $footer; ?>
```

Enabling them in php.ini `short_open_tag = On` fixed my issue.